# Import error when using netmiko with django : No module named '_cffi_backend'

Tags: python, django, automation, devops, cisco

Netmiko works fine when I execute below script file (test.py) from the linux cli

> #!/var/www/html/devopsenv/bin/python
>
> from netmiko import ConnectHandler import getpass
>
> cisco_asr = {
>       'device_type': 'cisco_xr',
>       'ip':   'my ip',
>       'username': 'user',
>       'password': 'pass',
>       'verbose': True }
>
> ```
> net_connect = ConnectHandler(**cisco_asr)
>
> config_commands = [ 'int BE222.2481',
>                    'vrf devops_test',
>                    'ip add 10.1.1.1/30']
>
> output = net_connect.send_config_set(config_commands)
> #net_connect.commit()
> print(output)
> ```

However when I try to use the same script from a django view by importing as below, I get the import error.

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
```

[import error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjOqp.png)

```
ImportError at /
No module named '_cffi_backend'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://W.X.Y.Z/
Django Version: 2.1.4
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
No module named '_cffi_backend'
Exception Location: /var/www/html/devopsenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bcrypt/__init__.py in <module>, line 25
Python Executable:  
Python Version: 3.5.6
Python Path:    
['/var/www/html/devops',
 '/var/www/html/devopsenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages',
 '/lib64/python35.zip',
 '/lib64/python3.5',
 '/lib64/python3.5/plat-linux',
 '/lib64/python3.5/lib-dynload',
 '/lib64/python3.5/site-packages',
 '/lib/python3.5/site-packages']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the problem
works perfectly with python 3.5
seems there is a bug on python 3.6 that causes it to throw the cffi-backend error when used with netmiko